# External Laravel server responds 401.2 Unauthorized error on connecting from localhost in an Angular app

Tags: angular, laravel, api, http

I am developing an **Angular app in localhost**. I tried to connect on a Laravel application **in a different Server** using the regular http component from angular.

In the Laravel, i have only one api route on api.php file, it returns the Ldap User.

I receive the error 401.2 when i try to access that route, **in the web browser the route works normally**, what could be happening?

I tried to find the answer here in a several topics but didn't find a problem like this.

Comment: We can't begin to help you, your question lack details. error 401.2 means o invalid authentication headers, have you checked the headers sent with the request ?

Comment: I'm not sending any headers, but inspecting the web browser that the request works, it creates an Authorization header **Authorization
 Negotiate YIIJIgYG...**, could be it?

Comment: most certainly it is that. see how you can remove that in your angular config